# Sendgrid - Cannot send email that contains an & special character in the 'to'

Tags: php, email, sendgrid

The email that we send to contains an '&' and the email does not send as it parses the & in a weird format and does not leave it intact!

It is like this
Subject : Feeback
TO : test&test@domain.com
Body : "Lorem Ipsum"

What can we do. We use this to send feedback from the web form to the email

Comment: How do you communicate with Sendgrid? (webhook/API/... => POST/GET). Must be a problem here because the ampersand is a valid e-mail character.

Comment: It sounds like you're using HTTP API. Make sure you're not encoding the `&` yourself before the Call. What's likely happening is that you're encoding it, then your API system is encoding it, so when SendGrid decodes it, it's still encoded one level.